# regex check for only these carrot characters

Tags: javascript, regex

What's the regex for just these characters `<>`. I was doing something like this which checks for to make sure only these are used.

```
function validateSpecialCharacters( value ){
    var regex = /^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+\s*$/;
    return (regex.test(value)) ? true : false;
}
```

Instead I want to check if `<` or `>` is been used if so return true

Updated:
This is what I used in the end.

```
function validateCaretCharacters( value ){
    var regex = /\<|\>/g;
    return (regex.test(value)) ? false : true;
}
```

so now if I enter a < or a > in the input field along with other text or numbers it will catch it and return false meaning it's not valid. I probably should change the name of the function to something more meaningful. 
Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You want to check if there is only `<>` or at least one of `<>` ?

Comment: Sorry check if there is one or more of both < and  >

Comment: Both ? or one of the two ?

Comment: @HamZa You should have asked what he wants !!? Where is the sample input or expected output ??

Comment: `^` is a *caret*. `<` and `>` are inequality signs :-)

Comment: @Sniffer I'm asking before posting an off-topic answer

Comment: I'm trying to stop script tags been entered in an input field. So I'm checking for either < or > character in the input field. So using regex was hoping to check for multiple inputs of carets.

Comment: @user1096509 this is a classic [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask (or search for) how to best sanitise input fields for HTML instead.

Comment: @user1096509 I hope you're also sanitizing on the server side too. Since someone could directly POST to your server side script bypassing all JS stuff...

Comment: Yes already done on the server side. It's more for UI validation.

Comment: @user1096509 I think you need to provide some context like \@Sniffer said: some input and expected output.

Comment: Example if someone adds text into the input like <spcipt> then my method will return true because < and > has been used. Or they could enter just "< example" and it will still return true

Comment: @user1096509 But what if the user has put `<hello` or `hello>` ? Let's make it complexer: `>hello<` or even `hello 4 < 5 and 8 > 7` and so on ...

Comment: What's important is that the user can not use carets < or > if they enter any caret in the input I want to check for it using regex

Comment: @user1096509 Fun fact: your regex does exactly what you need. It's a bit of a pain to ask 40 questions to come to this conclusion. Please be specific next time. Also if you didn't realise that then you should really learn the basics, you may start [here](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/). Your expression can be improved to `/^[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+$/`.

Comment: My function checks if the user has inputted only numbers or letters from a-z or A-Z. So any special characters outside that pattern will return false. The only special characters I'm looking out for are < and >

Comment: @user1096509 lol but if the input contains only letters, digits, spaces and comma then it's somehow "safe", isn't it ? Then you know that it doesn't contain `<>`.

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z0-9,\s]+$/. – throws an error in JS

Comment: [Impossible](http://jsfiddle.net/AuEcV/).

Comment: `return regex.test(value)` will do the same as your return.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

.test will return either true or false, so you're essentially saying if true, then true, else false.

```
var regex = /<|>/g;
if(regex.test(val)){
   // returned true - do something.
} else {
   // returned false - do something else.
}
```

should work for you.

Comment: Are you looking at a mirrored screen perhaps ?

Comment: I can't use this as a function in javascript.

Comment: sorry - it was hasty. try: var regex = /\<|\>/g;

Comment: @peterchon You don't need to escape `<>`, they are not special (when they are alone). But since we're this far, just use a character class `[<>]` :)

Comment: @peterchon because the syntax is wrong. I gave you a hint with my first comment. You should be using `/expression/` and not \expression\. PS: Most of the times I don't downvote answers :)

Comment: Exactly what I'm after thanks so much peterchon. I did need to escape in order for it to work in JS.

Comment: @user1096509 lol, that was not the truth, because there is a syntax error in that code and therefore will not work

Comment: @user1096509 For one hour I'm trying to help you with what should be done and what not, I've even improved your regex. But you turned it down and accepted this wrong answer ?

Comment: For an hour you have been making smart comments and making fun of my question. You have a strange way of helping man. I appreciate help but not rudeness.

Comment: @user1096509 I didn't make fun at all of your question, instead I tried to provide the best help possible by clarifying what you have and what you want. It turned out the expression you have does already take care of `<>` and don't accept them. "Rudeness" was only in the last comment when I said about checking your sanity, my bad. Well since this is what you were searching for, I think you should reformulate your question "how to match `<>`", but that will turn down to a "simple" question, which means one should learn the basics of regex. Take care, and sorry if I was rude ...

Comment: Apology accepted. And I agree I need to learn regex. Thanks for the help, and to all.

Comment: If you want to lear regex, look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions